# Mysql Getting Results Group by SUM + a row with the sum of descarted rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

i have the following question in mysql:

from a query like this:

```
select Category, count(*) as C 
from categories_likes 
group by Category 
order by C desc 
limit 3
```

I need to get a result like this:

```
Category | C
Love     | 10
Sad      | 5
Angry    | 3
Other    | 50
```

Where other is "Other" row is the sum of counts in the other categories not needed in the result but needed to group all in one last row.

Hope Somebody can help me.
Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to group all categories other than "Love", "Sad" and "Angry" in a unique group, called "Other".

If so, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select
    case 
        when category in ('Love', 'Sad', 'Angry') then category
        else 'Other'
    end new_category,
    count(*) cnt
from categories_like
group by new_category
order by (new_category = 'Other'), cnt desc
```

Note that the `order by` clause of the query puts category "Other" last.

---

If you want a dynamic top 3 of the categories, followed by the total count in all others categories, then it's a bit different. Assming MySQL 8.0, you can use a ranking function:

```
select case when rn <= 3  then category else 'Other' end new_category, sum(cnt) cnt
from (
    select category, count(*) cnt, rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from categories_like
    group by category
) t
group by new_category
order by (new_category = 'Other'), cnt desc
```

---

In earlier versions, I would suggest `union all`:

```
(
    select category new_category, count(*) cnt
    from categories_like
    group by category
    order by cnt desc
    limit 3
)
union all (
    select 'Other', sum(cnt)
    from (
        select category, count(*) cnt
        from categories_like
        group by category
        order by cnt desc
        limit 4, 1000
    ) t
)
order by (new_category = 'Other'), cnt desc
```

This assumes that there are not more than 1000 categories; you can increase the offset of the subquery as needed.

Comment: Hello Would be the second option, dynamic top3 and the Other would conglomerate all other categories, so this option would be only in Mysql 8? What about Mysql 5.7?

Comment: @MoisesVega: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.